# Using VBA to add a row after any row that contain a certain keyword and fill columns with data

Tags: excel, vba, row, addition

I need to add a row after any row that contains the keyword "skimmer", then fill columns with the following data:

columns A and B: match the data in this column from the row above.

columns D, F, H, I, J, K with text (these will always be the same)

here is what I have so far, this is not adding rows, it seems the code is not recognizing the keyword in the excel, even know the text is there..

```vb
Sub Skimmer()
Set rng2 = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
lr4 = rng2.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(3).Row

For i = lr4 To 2 Step -1
    If rng2.Cells(i, 11) Like "*Skimmer*" Then
        rng2.Cells(i, 11).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        rng2.Cells(i, 3).Offset(1).Resize(1, 9).Value = _
        Array("", "ColD", "", "ColF", "", "ColH", "ColI", "ColJ", "ColK")
        rng2.Cells(i, 1).Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Value = rng2.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Like` is case sensitive.

Comment: Your code is working. Can you share the data for which it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Insert Range Rows and Fill With Data

- This inserts rows in the range, not entire rows i.e. any data to the right of the range, stays intact.

**Compact**

```
Sub InsertSkimmersCompact()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim r As Long
    For r = rng2.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If LCase(rng2.Cells(r, "K").Value) Like "*skimmer*" Then
            With rng2.Rows(r).Offset(1)
                .Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                With .Offset(-1)
                    .Columns("A:B").Value = .Offset(-1).Columns("A:B").Value
                    .Columns("C:K").Value = Array("", "ColD", "", "ColF", _
                        "", "ColH", "ColI", "ColJ", "ColK")
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next r

    MsgBox "Skimmer-insertion complete.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Argumented**

```vb
Sub InsertSkimmersTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rng2 As Range:  Set rng2 = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    InsertSkimmers rng2
End Sub

Sub InsertSkimmers(ByVal rg As Range)
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = rg.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If LCase(rg.Cells(r, "K").Value) Like "*skimmer*" Then
            With rg.Rows(r).Offset(1)
                .Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                With .Offset(-1)
                    .Columns("A:B").Value = .Offset(-1).Columns("A:B").Value
                    .Columns("C:K").Value = Array("", "ColD", "", "ColF", _
                        "", "ColH", "ColI", "ColJ", "ColK")
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next r

    MsgBox "Skimmer-insertion complete.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: @Zac You should click the checkmark to accept this answer.